# Iterating through excel file, adding column to the series, and saving the results using the Panda library

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python's Panda library, how do you iterate through an excel file, add a column to the Series, and then write the results to a file?  Below is my attempt, but when I append to the Series the columns are turn into rows.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import re

df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Export.xlsx')

for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    account1= str(row1['ACCOUNT1'])
    not_found = 1
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        account2= str(row2['ACCOUNT2'])
        if re.search(account1, account2, re.IGNORECASE):
            row1["Results"] = "Found"
            not_found = 0   
            counter+=1
            print("found " + counter)
            data_writer = row1.append(row1)
            break
        if not_found ==1:
            row1["Results"] = "Found"
            counter += 1
            print("not found " + counter)
            data_writer = row1.append(row1)
data_writer.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
print("Finished")
```

below are the input files and expected output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please update with some example dataframe, what is input and what is  expected output.

Comment: @Nand i've added the expected output files

Comment: i really don't think its possible...Seems impossible to write columns to excel file using the Series data

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, but I just wish there was a shorter way of appending the existing data in the DataFrame without typing all the columns.  I just want to add a "Results" column to the dataframe to find out which columns matched.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Export.xlsx')

counter =0
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    account1= str(row1['ACCOUNT1'])
    not_found = 1
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        account2= str(row2['ACCOUNT2'])
        if re.search(account1, account2, re.IGNORECASE):
            not_found = 0   
            counter+=1
            print("found " + str(counter))
            new_dataframe = new_dataframe.append(pd.DataFrame({'Results': "Found",
            'ACCOUNT1': account1,
            'customer':row1['customer'],
            'state':row1['state'],
            'city':row1['city'] },
            index=[0]),
            ignore_index=True)
            break
    if not_found ==1:
        counter += 1
        print("not found " + str(counter))
        new_dataframe = new_dataframe.append(pd.DataFrame({'Results': "Not Found",
        'ACCOUNT1': account1,
        'customer':row1['customer'],
        'state':row1['state'],
        'city':row1['city'] }, index=[0]), ignore_index=True)           

new_dataframe.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
print("Finished")
```